# What is the translation of the French word "erre"?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, french

In French, there is a word [*erre*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erre_%28nautisme%29) which is the residual speed of a train, a ship or a car (or whatever is moving and needs propulsion).

For example, if you see a red light in your car, you stop accelerating, but you don't brake either; you just let the car move on its own. You can say that your car is *on erre*.

For a ship, if you cut the propulsion of the engine, you are *on erre*.

In a train, it is used if there is a switch of electrical alimentation. For a hundred meters, the train is no longer fed with electric power, and it continues moving with its residual speed. The train is *on erre*.

What is the best English expression for this?

Comment: what is *a switch of electrical alimentation*?

Comment: *alimentation* in French means *supply*.

Comment: Is it much used? It is in neither my Collins bilingual dictionary, nor in my Larousse Dictionnaire du français d'aujourd'hui.

Comment: @BarrieEngland  Try [this](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=son+erre)

Comment: It is definitely not a used expression. I think 99% of french people doesn't know it's existence!

Comment: Un-powered movement of the vehicle would amount to ***gliding*** -- however, we are more accustomed to its use with relation to aircraft only and not other forms of transport.

Answer (score 31):

For a car or a train, if you stop using the engine to propel it, you can say that you **coast** to a stop, or that the train (or car) is **coasting**. I haven't heard this used for boats (and Googling seems to indicate that if you **coast** in a boat, it often means that you are following the coastline), but I don't know what term would be used instead.

UPDATE: As Zairja remarks in the comments, for a boat the corresponding verb is *drift.*

Comment: I think that coasting for a car is more like put the gear on a neutral position. In french we called it "le point mort". It is not really the sense I'm seeking but thanks anyway for teaching me a new word :)

Comment: I think in English, for cars and trains, we would use the word *coast* both for the expression *courir sur son erre* and for putting the gear in neutral. I don't sail, so I don't know whether the same word is used for boats. Maybe you're looking for the word *inertia.*

Comment: When this occurs on a boat, you can call it [*drifting*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drifting) or say the boat is [*adrift*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adrift) ("without motive power and without anchor or mooring").

Comment: Coasting in a car does not imply that the gear is in a neutral position. It only means that there is no propulsion. If you let your foot off the accelerator, you are coasting.

Comment: In my mind, a boat that is *drifting* or *adrift* is likely not moving at all. I don't really know of a better word for a boat, though, except something more technical like *momentum* or *inertia*. (Though *inertia* could, again, apply equally to something that isn't moving.)

Comment: The problem with *drift* or *adrift* for a boat is that it gives the impression that the vessel is abandoned and, like Martha mentioned in the above comment, it does not necessarily indicate that the boat is actually moving at all.

Comment: @Marthaª: I almost-agree: to me "drifting" or "adrift" implies "moving with the current" -- people will even say, "drifting with the current" -- rather than "not moving"; but yeah, it doesn't generally imply that it's continuing forward momentum that it previously had.

Comment: Google has around the same number of hits for [boat drift to a stop](https://www.google.com/#q=%22boat+drift+to+a+stop%22&hl=en&prmd=imvnsb&ei=AmNrULLlE8vO0QHR14C4Ag&start=70&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=1491d37767182070&biw=1123&bih=671) and [boat coast to a stop](https://www.google.com/#q=%22boat+coast+to+a+stop%22&hl=en&prmd=imvns&ei=FWNrUPGhJuT30gHT54DoDw&start=40&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=1491d37767182070&biw=1123&bih=671), so I think *drift* works. I don't think *adrift* does, though; that seems to me to indicate that the boat is at the mercy of the currents and wind.

Answer (score 17):

I think the word you are looking for here is [*momentum*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/momentum), as in *traveling on momentum alone*.

> **momentum** *n*
>     2. (Physics / General Physics) the impetus of a body resulting from its motion

Comment: And the idiom is the unusually long "travelling under its own momentum". "Coasting" saves a lot of keystrokes.

Comment: @StoneyB: The OP was looking for an equivalent to *on erre*. The question was not about how to save keystrokes.

Comment: @StoneyB The car "continued on momentum" versus "was *on erre*" or "coasted" isn't that much longer. You could also say something "pushed/moved/kept/went on/by momentum".

Comment: @Robusto   Sorry, I misread your answer as offering "momentum" by itself as the answer. Haste makes embarrassment.

Answer (score 6):

The train is '*traveling under its own inertia*':

> Inertia is the resistance of any physical object to a change in its state of motion or rest, or the tendency of an object to resist any change in its motion.

The train is resisting the frictional forces acting on it, and thus slows, but continues without an external driving force acting on it.

Comment: I don't speak much French, but I do know that the word *inertie* (= *inertia*) also exists in French. But perhaps *inertie* has a different nuance of meaning from *inertia* in non-technical usage?

Comment: Argh, “it’s” => “its”.

Comment: @KonradRudolph mischief managed

Comment: I like this one, simple, can be use in french too, and have the exact same meaning. We can said "the train is on his inertia" as well as "le train est sur son inertie".

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider [freewheel](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/freewheel):

> 1. (of a gear) To continue spinning after disengagement.
> 2. (of a cyclist) To ride a bicycle without pedalling, e.g. downhill.
> 3. (of a motorist) To operate a motor vehicle which is coasting without power, e.g. downhill.
> 4. (by extension) To operate free from constraints.

Wikipedia has a page [devoted to this subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freewheel):

> The condition of a driven shaft spinning faster than its driveshaft exists in most bicycles when the rider holds his or her feet still, no longer pushing the pedals. In a fixed-gear bicycle, without a freewheel, the rear wheel would drive the pedals around.
>
> An analogous condition exists in an automobile with a manual transmission going down hill or any situation where the driver takes his foot off the gas pedal, closing the throttle; the wheels want to drive the engine, possibly at a higher RPM.

P.S. The word is more often used in its [figurative sense](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freewheeling).